# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscribe' Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, reactive

I am new to Reactive programming, and I'm trying to observe a boolean value from my ViewModel in order to let my ViewController know when to start/stop the app's loader screen.

It's fairly simple and I want to use this method to avoid unnecessary delegates, since my ViewModel holds the business logic and my ViewController handles the UI.

My problem is this compiler error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscribe'`.

It also adds the two possible candidates, as you can see in the image below:
[image: description of error]
In my ViewModel, I've declared the observable as PublishSubject:

```
let done = PublishSubject<Bool>()
```

And I use it while observing another stream:

```
func subscribe() {
    done.onNext(false)
    anotherObservable.subscribe(

        // other events observed here but not relevant to this matter

        onCompleted: {
            self.done.onNext(true)

    }).addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
}
```

And, finally, this is how I'm trying to handle it in the ViewController:

```
self.model.done.subscribe(
    .onNext { isDone in

        if isDone {
            self.removeLoader()
        }
}).addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
```

I believe there is something simple I'm probably missing, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second subscribe should be:

```
self.model.done.subscribe(onNext: { isDone in
   if isDone {
      self.removeLoader()
   }
}).addDisposableTo(rx_disposeBag)
```

Comment: Yes. I was mixing the syntax to emit and handle the events. Thanks for your answer!